# Printable, dynamically generated forms created from data stored as XML?

Tags: xml, forms, printing

---

I am a somewhat new programmer working on a small project; the software I am designing will eventually handle loading and saving XML data and producing forms. The forms make up an electronic chart for a small medical practice and due to the varied requirements of each client and each chart the forms will be generated dynamically based on the information stored.

I've been playing with creating a series of forms in HTML that will work to a degree, but it has become apparent that this approach is fundamentally flawed; nothing is going to allow me to run a local HTML and javascript application in a browser and get adequate access to the file-system to load and save XML files.

I am looking for a new approach. Currently I'm considering trying out Adobe AIR. I have some Java experience but I am unsure how effectively I can create attractive forms in Java. In terms of either approach I need to consider the ability to print the forms created by the application.

Does anyone have any advice for existing technologies I can experiment with, in order to get this application up and running?

### TL;DR

I'm looking to write a (local, non-web) application with the following features:

- Create attractive, electronic forms.
- Load/Save data from (local) XML files.
- Print the forms.

I'm unsure what technologies might suit the project but I'm currently looking at Adobe AIR because I'm most experienced with Javascript. Any advice?